# how to get from parameters more than one word in each paramater (discord.py)

Tags: python, parameter-passing, discord.py

my question is simple ,and i don't know if it has been answered before because i couldn't find an answer.So i'm trying this idea about when someone types a word the bot would automatically reply with a specific reply, i'm making a command to add these things, but i'm having a problem, which is that each parameter gets only the first and the second input,and i want to split them from each other, here's a small example:

```
@client.command()
async def areply(ctx,word, info):
```

Comment: You can view (this)[https://realpython.com/python-kwargs-and-args/] for some more detail however you can use `(ctx, *, words)` to accept all words after the command call, then you can just split it on spaces. If you only wanted the first word split you could use `(ctx, *words)` to create a tuple, remove the first indexed item and join the rest

Comment: I couldn't understand your question, can you explain more?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `*` which will take every word after the second parameter as user input, for example:

```
@client.command()
async def areply(ctx, word, *, info):
    await ctx.send(f"The word provided was: `{word}` and the information provided was: `{info}`")
```

Lets say a user typed `!areply Example This is test info`, the bot will output the following:

> The word provided was: `Example` and the information provided was: `This is test info`